# Duplicate rows in text file

Tags: bash, text-processing

I need to duplicate rows in text file with a specific number of times. For example my data file is:

```
jplg3350.18i
jplg3360.18i
jplg3370.18i
```

I need to duplicate the lines three times as follows;

```
jplg3350.18i
jplg3360.18i
jplg3370.18i
jplg3350.18i
jplg3360.18i
jplg3370.18i
jplg3350.18i
jplg3360.18i
jplg3370.18i
```

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/q/338616/418028

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For 3 times you can just run:

```
cat file file file > new_file
```

And here is a trick if you're lazy like me and you don't want to re-type the file name N times. Type `cat` then the filename, Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> `N` times, finally type `> new_file`.

---

However it's a better idea to use a simple "loop" in combination with `cat` command.

- 3 times example:

  ```
  for i in {1..3}; do cat file >> new_file; done
  ```

Or as you asked in comments:

```
limit=3
for ((i=0; i<limit; i++)); do cat file >> new_file; done
```

Change '3' to any number you want.

Result:

```
jplg3350.18i
jplg3360.18i
jplg3370.18i
jplg3350.18i
jplg3360.18i
jplg3370.18i
jplg3350.18i
jplg3360.18i
jplg3370.18i
```

Comment: You couldn't even let the little guys take this one! Happy New Year Rav!

Comment: :)) Happy to you too George ;)

Comment: Another lazy trick is to use brace expansion with an empty string: `cat file{,,} > new_file`